# e-mail submit form error

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I have a form for e-mail submissions on my page and I can't find what is causing it to kick back an unsuccessful submission.  Below are the portions of code concerning the form.  I circumvented the js and just used the php script directly and the mail sent, so that doesn't appear to be the problem.  Any ideas?

js:

```
    $('#button-send').click(function(event){
        $('#button-send').html('Sending E-Mail...');
        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').scrollTo( $('#contact'), 'fast' );
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'send_form_email.php',
            data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
            success: function(html) {
                if(html.success == '1')
                {
                    $('#button-send').html('Send E-Mail');
                    $('#success').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#button-send').html('Send E-Mail');
                    $('#error').show();
                }                   
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#button-send').html('Send E-Mail');
                $('#error').show();
            }
        });

    });


});


function valemail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$send_email_to = "me@myemail";
$email_subject = "New Message";
function send_email($name,$email,$email_message)
{
  global $send_email_to;
  global $email_subject;
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ".$email. "\r\n";
  $message = "<strong>Email = </strong>".$email."<br>";
  $message .= "<strong>Name = </strong>".$name."<br>";  
  $message .= "<strong>Message = </strong>".$email_message."<br>";
  @mail($send_email_to, $email_subject, $message,$headers);
  return true;
}

function validate($name,$email,$message)
{
  $return_array = array();
  $return_array['success'] = '1';
  $return_array['name_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['email_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['message_msg'] = '';
  if($email == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['email_msg'] = 'email is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['email_msg'] = 'enter valid email.';  
    }
  }
  if($name == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['name_msg'] = 'name is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['name_msg'] = 'enter valid name.';
    }
  }

  if($message == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['message_msg'] = 'message is required';
  }
  else
  {
    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['message_msg'] = 'enter valid message.';
    }
  }
  return $return_array;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$return_array = validate($name,$email,$message);

if($return_array['success'] == '1')
{
    send_email($name,$email,$message);
}
header('Content-type: text/json')
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();
?>
```

and the HTML on my page:

```
        <form method="post" action="send_form_email.php" id="contactform">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Enter your name</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-field" id="name" name="name" value="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Enter your e-mail</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-field" id="email" name="email" value="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Type Your Message</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <a id="button-send" href="#" title="Send Email" class="button" style="width:100%;">Send E-Mail</a>
            <div id="success">Your message has been successfully!</div>
            <div id="error">Unable to send your message, please try later.</div>
        </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "kick back an unsuccessful submission"?  I'd suggest removing the error suppression (the @ symbol in front of the function) from the mail() call.  Also, what is the OS?  It makes a difference with PHP mail.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.  From the front end, on form submission, it shows "Unable to send your message, please try later."  As I mentioned, I tested the php script by replacing the current button with a submit type input and it sent the mail just fine after calling the php script.  I have very little Java experience so I'm having a hard time determining where things are going wrong when using the ajax.

Comment: I found the following error in my apache logs

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING) in /var/www/html/send_form_email.php on line 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put semi-colon like this header('Content-type: text/json');

Comment: I can't believe I missed that somehow :|

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a little while troubleshooting this code which I got with a HTML5 theme I downloaded from eGrappler a while ago, so to save time for anyone else who stumbles across this post like I did, the example code appears to have another error and likely wouldn't work.

In the .js it states

> "data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),"

however the id of the form in the HTML is "contactform" without the underscore

> id="contactform">"

These need to match, otherwise the post won't contain the name, email address, or message and the email won't ever send.

Hopefully that saves someone else from the debugging I did.. got there in the end, but it was a learning curve!